# SQL create row_number from multiple string columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, row-number, unique-values

I have in my table 3 string column and I want to create unique column with a row_nubmer.
I have tried something like this but didn't get unique values:

```
ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY ([Marker1] + [Marker2] + [Marker3])
     ORDER BY ([Marker1] + [Marker2] + [Marker3])  DESC) ROWNUMBER
```

Comment: remove the `partition by` clause

Comment: But still didn't get unique values for all 3 columns. Now I have rownuber long as table is.. I need that one rownumber is for the same combination of ([Marker1] + [Marker2] + [Marker3]) values.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `DENSE RANK` function:

```
DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY [Marker1], [Marker2], [Marker3]) AS ROWNUMBER
```

Note that you do not need to concatenate strings to identify unique values. This can lead to false positives.

```
A   B   A+B
-----------
XX  X   XXX
X   XX  XXX
```

Comment: If it answers your question please mark it as accepted.